# As a management account/delegated admin in a AWS Organization, how to call AWS services for each member account in AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

Say I set up a AWS organization from account 111111111111, and then I create/invite 2 accounts, 222222222222 and 33333333333. As soon as I enabled SCP, I see a `FullAWSAccess` Policy attached to all members. I am trying to update each account programmatically in AWS SDK, and not having to switch roles on Console each time. For example:

```
AWSOrganizations client = AWSOrganizationsClientBuilder.standard().build();
ListAccountsResult result = client.listAccounts(new ListAccountsRequest().withMaxResults(10))
result.getAccounts()
      .stream()
      .forEach(account -> {
          // I am not sure what to do with below data
          // account.getArn()
          // account.getId()
      })
```

Say I want each member to put a s3 object like so:

```
s3.putObject(..)
```

Do I need to assume a role (AWS creates a `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` role by default) for each member account and call AWS service? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, in order to execute actions in other member accounts you need to assume a role in that account first. AWS Organizations creates `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` in each newly created account, this role has a trust policy to trust the master account. So as long as you're authenticated to the master account with any role that has `sts:AssumeRole` action you can assume `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` in the target account and do the "needfuls".

As the best practise you should your own automation role  in each account and a dedicated automation account. This automation role lets say "pipeline-role" will have limited permissions that can be assumed only from your automation account.

This way you're reducing the need to utilise your master account and also making this automation role only as powerful as your automation needs instead of using the full AdministratorAccess policy.